# The dual space of $L^1_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the subspace of $L^1 (\mathbb{R}^n)$ functions with vanishing integral.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces, quotient-spaces, complete-spaces, dual-spaces

Let an equivalence relation in $L^{\infty}=L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as follows: we say that $\varphi \sim \varphi_1$ if $\varphi -\varphi_1= c$ a.e.

We identifying those $L^{\infty}$ functions that differ by a constant, and denote the equivalence class corresponding to $\varphi \in L^{\infty}$ by $\phi$. Now let $(\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n), \|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{L}^{\infty}})$ denote
the  $L^{\infty}$ modulo constants space endowed with the quotient norm, that is, 
$$\| \phi \|_{\mathcal{L}^{\infty}} = \inf \{ \|\varphi\|_{L^{\infty}}:\varphi \in \phi \}, \phi \in \mathcal{L}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n).$$
Show that

(a) $(\mathcal{L}^{\infty}, \|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{L}^{\infty}})$ is Banach space ;

(b)$(\mathcal{L}^{\infty}, \|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{L}^{\infty}})$ is the dual space of $L^1_0$, where $L^1_0=L^1_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the subspace of $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ functions with vanishing integral.

I  think $ \mathcal{L}^{\infty} = L^{\infty }/_{\sim}$. 
For (a), I can't prove that $(\mathcal{L}^{\infty}, \|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{L}^{\infty}})$  is complete. 
For (b), I was trying to prove it by using Riesz Theorem similarly into proof $L^{\infty} $ is dual space of $L^1$ but there is no progress.
Could you please prove or give me some references for the proof of this result?

Comment: Let $M$ be the space of all constants. Then $M$ is a closed subspace of $L^{1}$. This implies $L^{1}/M$ is a Banach space and its dual is precisely $\{f \in L^{\infty}: f(M)=0\}$. When you think of a function $f \in L^{\infty}$ as a linear functional on $L^{1}$, the function vanishes on $M$ iff its integral is 0. Thus, you only have to quote basic facts about quotients of Banach spaces by closed subspaces.

Comment: I don't understand why its dual is $\{ f \in L^{\infty }:f(M)=0\} $. And I think you maybe confused between $L^1$ and $L^{\infty}$...

Comment: In my opinion, the dual space of $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}$ maybe is $L^1_0$ but it can't follow that the dual space of $L^1_0$ is $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}$. Do you agree with me?

Comment: The dual of $L^{\infty}$ is the space of finitely additive measures.

Comment: No, the dual of $L^{\infty}$ is much much bigger than $L_0^{1}$.